# Программная реализация V-USB CodeVisionAVR

Tags: usb, микроконтроллеры, avr

Дорогие радио любители, есть ли у кого-то код (или может ли кто-то состряпать) для **CodeVisionAVR** программной реализации **V-USB**? сделал простенькое устройство (по указаниям с сайта [USB для AVR. Часть 2. HID Class на V-USB](http://we.easyelectronics.ru/electro-and-pc/usb-dlya-avr-chast-2-hid-class-na-v-usb.html)). Все работает, все великолепно, зашивал через как вы уже поняли `CVAVR`! Единственный минус - я мало что понимаю в `AVRStudio`. А сам проект, запуская компилятор, обнаруживает ошибку! Хотел было использовать `AVRStudio` как прошивальщик... в итоге перевел по ошибке, незнанию микроконтроллер в параллельное (могу ошибаться) программирование... и убедительная просьба - не надо только советовать и говорить про сайты, в которых упоминается `V-USB`, так-как там везде используется `AVRStudio` или еще какай нибудь другой компилятор... а очень нужно, подойдет даже самый *худой* проект на **CodeVisionAVR** для реализации **программного USB**...

**P.S.** ***Искреннее спасибо за ваше внимание и время, а также простите меня, если я был не прав***

Answer (score 2):

Делал такое HID устройство (не мышь) и тоже хотел использовать CodeVisionAVR, но ничего не получилось. Промучился пару дней. Так что пришлось сделать как на сайтах - при помощи AVRStudio. Если нужно могу выслать готовый рабочий проект для примера.